# set a default item in a tab bar of type UITabBar (Not UITabBarViewController), in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Using Swift 2 for iOS
How to set a default selected item in a tab bar of type UITabBar (Not UITabBarViewController), in viewDidLoad

detailed information:
i am creating my own tab view nib file, i need to find a way to allow
the tab bar to set a default item during viewDidLoad, i tried 
these methods that I would often use for TabBarViewController but they are not found in the UITabBar

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
self.tabBar?.selectedIndex = 0
```

even trying `self.UITabBar?.selectedIndex = 0` did not work
i also tried `tabBar.selectedIndex = tabBar.title("Tab1")`

i am still a beginner in swift, i really apprciate some help, and thank you in advance

if this is not clear enough let me know :)

Comment: searching further i found this in the UITabBar Xcode details but i still didn't find out how to use it  'public var items: [UITabBarItem]? // get/set visible UITabBarItems. default is nil. changes not animated. shown in order'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your tabbar is allocated because self.tabbar?.selectedIndex won't work but neither will crash if your tabbar is nil.

Or have you tried something like this :
`self.tabbar.selectedItem = self.tabbar.items![0]`
did not test it but maybe it works.

Comment: this highlighted the tab item i want, but after the view loaded it did not show it's content, i had to press on it again, any more ideas i can try ?

Comment: thank you for your help, i combined your hint with some try and error :D and it was solved, i will mark this as solved, and this is how it ended up .  'tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0]'
'tabBar(tabBar, didSelectItem: tabBar.items![0])' //adding this in viewDidLoad solved everything